# Null checking in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I my web application I am using I-REPORT designer for designing report.
For the data used in report,I have written a query that fetch two column values from different table.Here data type of column data is **real**.In ireport corresponding data type is **Float**.

Here,if one of the data have a value,other have a no value or empty.So I have to display a value that is not null or empty using text field,when the report is generated.So I have implemented condition in text field

```
( $F{permit_quantity}==null ?$F{fst_insp_qpqlml_quantity} : $F{permit_quantity} )
```

Here the fields $F{permit_quantity}, $F{fst_insp_qpqlml_quantity} corresponding to two column values returned by query.

But the above condition is not working when $F{permit_quantity} is empty or null.

I am using **postgresql** database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `.equals()` Method if the condition itself is not working.

`$F{permit_quantity}.equals(null) ? $F{fst_insp_qpqlml_quantity} : $F{permit_quantity}`

There could be various other reasons why your code doesn´t work but I can´t tell from your snippet.

Comment: Surely this will be worse. If you try to call `.equals()` on a null reference a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Comment: You´re absolutely right. Please ignore this Answer. Don´t use `.equals()` for Nullchecking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $F{permit_quantity}.toString() == null ? $F{fst_insp_qpqlml_quantity} :  
 $F{permit_quantity}
```

This solves your problem.